# Letting users create a chatroom when placing a marker with Quicklox and Google maps

Tags: java, objective-c, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-sdk-ios, quickblox

After looking through the location based chat samples for iOS and Android with the QuickBlox SDK I'm interested in using a feature, where not only when a user displays their location on a map but marks one that they can create a group chat room. I'd like the chatroom to be named after the marker. When user creates a marker I'd prefer that the link to the chatroom would be in the infowindow. I'd also prefer that the option to make a chatroom is asked when putting in content into the infowindow.
I suspect having to create a formula for the marker classes but I also want to figure if the chatroom will also appear in the chatroom sections of my app.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting idea. Good luck.

Comment: That is interesting...and that sounds like an entire app which is probably way more code that should be shown in an answer here (lots of obj c and PHP).  But it's do-able

Comment: It should be possible I just looked over again and they stated this      "Link rooms to specific objects (example: DSTV app has pre-defined QB chat rooms for each TV channel to enable discussion of the latest shows)
Link rooms to users (for example company divisions or game clans can chat in one room - you can also secure access to rooms by setting a password or via Users Tags)
Link rooms to locations (similar to topics/objects but each room has a Location property and can then be found on map / AR mode and be filtered / accessed on users current location basis - also see [location based chat]